# ¿Por qué el método onMessageReceived de la clase MyFirebaseMessagingService no recibe ningún Custom Data en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-messaging

Estoy implementando el servicio de notificaciones push para una aplicación en Android. Las notificaciones llegan correctamente, sin embargo, **la clase `MyFirebaseMessagingService` que recomienda la documentación de Firebase no logra recuperar los Custom Data que yo envío desde la sección de *Compose Notification*** (Messaging  > New Campaign > Notifications).

En la siguiente imagen muestro cómo estoy enviando dos Custom Data:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la notificación sí llega a mi dispositivo Android:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi clase `MyFirebaseMessagingService` contiene:

```
package com.laciudadbabasonica;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

@SuppressLint("MissingFirebaseInstanceTokenRefresh")
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // ...
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: https://goo.gl/39bRNJ
        // Log.d("from_frb", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
                // scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                // handleNow();
            }
            Log.i("message_recieved", "estoy recibiendo algo...");
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
}
```

Me gustaría saber qué estoy omitiendo o haciendo de manera incorrecta.

Answer (score 0):

Después de haber buscado mucho en el foro en inglés, llegué a la solución, la cual explicaré a continuación:

1. En base a [esta referencia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyHqU.png) me di cuenta que la clase MyFirebaseMessagingService solo es útil para leer la notificación enviada cuando la aplicación se encuentra abierta (o sea, cuando no está en background).
2. En base a lo anterior dicho y siguiendo [esta otra referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42279260/6119009) caí en cuenta que necesitaba añadir más código en la clase principal donde tengo definido mi `intent` por default, la cual es una clase `SplashActivity` la cual se encarga de mostrar un splash screen antes de iniciar la aplicación. Mi problema en sí era que estaba tratando de leer los `Bundle` en mi `MainActivity` cuando en realidad necesitaba leerlo desde mi clase `SplashActivity.java` como lo siguiente:

---

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myawesomeapp" >

    ...

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        ...
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ...
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages.
     See README(https://goo.gl/l4GJaQ) for more. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
        <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
             notification message. See README(https://goo.gl/6BKBk7) for more. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

SplashActivity.java

```
package com.laciudadbabasonica;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import Activities.MainActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            //bundle must contain all info sent in "data" field of the notification
            Toast.makeText(this, "SE ESTAN RECIBIENDO DATOS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("cb_action", bundle.getString("cb_action"));
            Log.i("cb_value", bundle.getString("cb_value"));
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NO SE HA RECIBIDO NADA AUN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Log.i();
        }
    }
}
```

Leer los `Bundle` desde mi `SplashActivity` era necesario porque como antes lo estaba leyendo desde mi `MainActivity`, al momento de llegar a esta clase, los `Bundle` que `Firebase Cloud Messaging` enviaba ya no llegaban en esta clase.

### Notas adicionales

Para enviar las notificaciones push me apoyé del lenguaje PHP, en donde me posibilita enviar un en el `payload` mi objeto `data` y así poder leerlo desde mi `SplashActivity`, el código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
// Server key from Firebase Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR_FIREBASE_CLOUD_MESSAGING_API_KEY_FROM_GOOGLE_CLOUD' );

$data = array(
    "to" => "YOUR_FIREBASE_TOKEN_DEVICE",
    "data" => array(
        "cb_action" => "nueva_fecha",
        "cb_value" => "1"
    ),
    "notification" => array( 
        "title" => "Mi asombroso titulo de notificacion", 
        "body" => "El gran contenido de la notificación.",
    )
);
$data_string = json_encode($data); 

//echo "The Json Data : ".$data_string; 

$headers = array
(
     'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY, 
     'Content-Type: application/json'
);                                                                                 
                                                                                                                     
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );                                                                  
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );  
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
                                                                                                                     
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.